# VBA Multi dimensional array in a dictionary

Tags: arrays, vba, dictionary

I am trying to store a multi dimensional array in VBA. I added the array to a key but I am not sure how I access it. I need to save an array of three for each key. The main array is a list of 15, 3 dimensional arrays.

```
Function test22()
  'Instanciate variables
  Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary
  Dim hello As String
  hello = "Hello world"

  Dim test(0 To 15, 0 To 2) As String
  test(0, 0) = hello
  dict.add "key1", test

  'This line should print Hello World
  Debug.Print dict("key1").Value(0, 0)
End Function
```

Comment: What is an array of three?

Comment: Try declaring a variant and assigning the item to it: myVariable = dict("key1"). You should then be able to use myvariable as an MD array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want

```
Debug.Print dict("key1")(0, 0)
```

`dict("key1")` will return an array. You then specify the location in that array directly as you would normally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but one more question. Is it possible to store the test 2 dimensional array in a dictionary. But I only want to store the first list in the array. I am trying but I get a wrong dimension error.

Comment: Please explain a little more. What is the code line that is failing for you?

Comment: For I = 0 To 15
        'Data which should be going in for that key
        If I < 8 Then
            keyArray(I, 0) = departmentalData(I)
        Else
            keyArray(I, 0) = TBSdata(I - 8)
        End If
            keyArray(I, 1) = keys(I, 0)
            keyArray(I, 2) = keys(I, 1)
            keyArray(I, 3) = keys(I, 2)
            
            dict.Add keys(I, 0) & " " & keys(I, 1) & " " & keys(I, 2), keyArray(I)
    Next I

Comment: Sorry the code is formatted really poorly. What I am trying to do is have three attributes combined to make the primary key which is what I use for searching and I want an array of that key broken down.

Comment: dict.Add keys(I, 0) & " " & keys(I, 1) & " " & keys(I, 2), keyArray(I)

Comment: Where has keys come from ? As in keys(i,1)  ?

Comment: keys is a 3d array which was declared earlier in my code. The three values is what makes up my primary key. So essentially using keys I want to store the keys separated

Comment: Here is the declaratin: Dim keys(15, 3) As String

Comment: Sorry if I am slow but what does "using keys I want to store the keys separated"" mean?

Comment: You could post a new question and it might be easier with more space for you to show the entiire code and highlight on which line the problem is along with the error message.

Comment: I'm on a train with intermittent signal I'm afraid at present.